# Cannot autowire argument : Symfony 4

Tags: symfony

I'v just download a package with composer via : composer require cocur/slugify

When i try to use dependency injection with it i got this error :
Cannot autowire argument $slugify of "App\Controller\MainController::index()": it references class "Cocur\Slugify\Slugify" but no such service exists.

Can you tell me why dependency injection is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure you have added a slugify bundle to your `config/bundles.php` (in case you use Symfony 4). Also, it's better to use the `\Cocur\Slugify\SlugifyInterface` instead of `Cocur\Slugify\Slugify`.

```
return [
    // ...
    Cocur\Slugify\Bridge\Symfony\CocurSlugifyBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

For Symfony 3 it should be added to `app/AppKernel.php`.

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            // ...
            new Cocur\Slugify\Bridge\Symfony\CocurSlugifyBundle(),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why was i forced to do that step ?

Comment: This step adds a bundle to your project, so all bundle's services would be compiled within your container and you'll be able to use them via auto wiring.